# Javascript flash screen does not disappear

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat

I have a [Pakistani chat rooms](http://www.hihellobye.com/pakistani-chat-rooms.html) website. I have added a facebook like flash screen. However, every time I need to click "close" button. Is there a way that once a chatter click close button then he doesn't need to press close button on every chat rooms pages?

I am looking for a method to disable javascript flash screen on my website. Thanks to Sergio solution! it works now.

Comment: Sergio answered it :) It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a flag variable in localStorage:

```
$("#the-close-button").on("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem("show-modal", "1");
});
```

And wrap the code to show the modal with:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("show-modal") != null) {
  // Show your modal code...
}
```